# VI switch and replace with vi.

Tags: vim

This is a config file, and a swith failed, so the networking 
guy wanted to set up a new path to the swith, and I needed to change the ports - FAST. 
So what i used was %s/:64*$/:57000/g and that did not change them. 
I ended up doing them by hand. How could I quickly have changed the :
in vi?

```
Addr.corp-unix-b1 = corp6503xap:64001
Addr.corp-unix-b2 = corp6503xap:64002
Addr.corp-unix-b3 = corp6503xap:64003
Addr.corp-unix-b4 = corp6503xap:64004
Addr.corp-unix-b4-dia = corp6503xap:64005
Addr.corp-unix-b5 = corp6503xap:64006
Addr.corp-unix-b6 = corp6504xap:64007
Addr.corp-unix-b6-aapl = corp6504xap:64008
Addr.corp-unix-b7 = corp6504xap:64009
Addr.corp-unix-b8 = corp6504xap:64010
Addr.corp-unix-b8-spy = corp6504xap:64011
Addr.corp-unix-b8-fas = corp6504xap:64012
Addr.corp-unix-b8-2 = corp6504xap:64013
Addr.corp-unix-8a-gld = corp6504xap:64014
Addr.corp-unix-b9 = corp6504xap:64015
Addr.corp-unix-b10 = corp6504xap:64016
Addr.togen-xpho-b6-aapl = corp9189pap:3333
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression is missing a `.`, so you were trying to match `6` followed by a variable number of 4's. If you have the `.`, then you are matching the expression `64` followed by a variable number of any character to the end of line.

```
%s/:64.*$/:57000/g
```

Answer (score 2):

In regular expressions, `*` indicates 0 or more of the preceding character, which in your case is `4`.

`.` matches any character, so your substitution would be written `:%s/:64.*$/:57000/g`

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an alternate solution in the spirit of SE:

You could use `:g` in combination with `:normal`

```
:g/:64/norm $bC57000
```

This finds lines with `:64`, goes to the end of the line, moves the cursor to the beginning of the word and changes the remaining of the line to 57000.